# Error plotting the logistic regression curve in Python

Tags: python, scikit-learn

ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (6,500) (6,)

I don´t know how to change the shapes of the variables. Just know that clf.coef_ is different from clf.intercept_.

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression

x = np.array(dados['Satisfacao_acess'])
y = np.array(dados['Satisf_usoacess'])

print(y.shape)
print(x.shape)

clf = LogisticRegression(C=1e7)
clf.fit(x.reshape(-1,1), y)

def model(x):
    return 1 / (1 + np.exp(-x))

print(clf.coef_.shape)
print (clf.intercept_.shape)

line = np.linspace(1, 110, 500)
line = model(line * clf.coef_+ clf.intercept_).ravel()


plt.scatter(x, y)
plt.plot(np.linspace(1, 110, 500), line, c='C1')
plt.axvline(x=0.5 - (clf.intercept_/clf.coef_), c='k', ls='dotted', lw=1)
plt.show()

print('Acurácia: %.3f' % clf.score(x.reshape(-1,1), y))
print('Os parâmetros do modelos são: %.3f, %.3f' % (clf.intercept_, clf.coef_))
```

Output:

```
(57,)
(57,)
(6, 1)
(6,)
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sklearn/linear_model/logistic.py:432: FutureWarning: Default solver will be changed to 'lbfgs' in 0.22. Specify a solver to silence this warning.
  FutureWarning)
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sklearn/linear_model/logistic.py:469: FutureWarning: Default multi_class will be changed to 'auto' in 0.22. Specify the multi_class option to silence this warning."this warning.", FutureWarning)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-150-da96d96d5c71> in <module>()
     17 
     18 line = np.linspace(1, 110, 500)
---> 19 line = model(line * clf.coef_+ clf.intercept_).ravel()
     20 
     21 
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (6,500) (6,)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have some misunderstanding of how the [LogisticRegression](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html) method works in sci-kit learn.

This is how shape of each of the `attributes` is generated.

- `coef_` - shape(1, n_features) or in your case shape(n_classes, n_features)
- `intercept_` - shape(1, ) or in your case shape(n_classes, )

From the sample output looks like you have only 1 feature and 6 classes.

So you will have to generate 6 separate lines. The formula you are using is accurate.

```py
# Repeat line 6 times
line = np.tile(np.linspace(1, 100, 500), (6, 1))

# Reshape intercept to add to each row element
# Generate a (6, 500) matrix
# 6 lines, 500 points each
line = model(line * clf.coef_ + clf.intercept_.reshape(6, 1)).ravel()
```

This will return the results value for 6 separate line (each for a separate class) for the range of `x` values of `np.linspace(1, 100, 500)`

Comment: Great! My data has 6 features, you´re right, thanks!
But now it returns the error:
---> line = model(line * clf.coef_+ clf.intercept_.reshape(6,1)).ravel()
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'

Comment: Just make sure all `line` is of type `float`. Convert to float by`float(<object>)`. This should do the trick.